# screenshot function for functional test with internjs Framework doens't work

Tags: javascript, automation, css-selectors, intern, leadfoot

I'm using the intern framework for functional testing and running browser locally (Firefox version 39). Is there a way to capture screenshot png-file? I tried the following example [How to take a screenshot with local browser (FF) and write to file in intern javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684999/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-local-browser-ff-and-write-to-file-in-intern-jav) but I get this error

**" node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:757
throw new Error('Failed to load module ' + module.mid + ' from ' + url + ".**

I'm a beginner to this intern js framework and leadfood.

Thank you very much for looking in.

Here is what I have:

```
 define([
            'intern!object',
            'intern/chai!assert',
            'require',
            'tests/support/personas'
        ], function (registerSuite, assert, require, personas) {

            registerSuite({
                name: 'index',
                'greeting form': function () {
                    var persona = personas[0]
                    return this.remote
                        .get(require.toUrl('https://www.google.de/'))
                        .setFindTimeout(5000)
                        //.setFindTimeout(5000)
                      .findByCssSelector('input[id="billingAddress.zip"]')
                              .click()
                              .type('50800')
                              .end()

                    .getCurrentUrl()
                    .takeScreenshot
                    .then(function (data) {
                    fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/myCapture', data,'base64');
                    )}
```

Comment: Your implementation of takeScreenshot seems correct though.
It returns a promise containing a buffer that's base64 encoded.
https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Command.html#takeScreenshot


Can you post your full code please?
This doesn't appear to be the full source.

Comment: hey @DLeonardi here is the complete script code http://codeshare.io/VcXi2 but the script is not done at the moment, i use it to test our zip validation process.The Screenshot function start in Line 234.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to take a screenshot with local browser (FF) and write to file in intern javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684999/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-local-browser-ff-and-write-to-file-in-intern-jav)

Answer (score 0):

OK you're seeing an error here because of the way in which you're telling intern to navigate to the URL.

You are using `.get(require.toUrl('https://www.google.de/'))` which is incorrect. You only use `.get(require.toUrl('...'))` with intern **version 3** and **only** if you are asking intern to open a static web page from a file on your local machine.

So if / when you're using the `.get(require.toUrl('...'))` method, you should be sending it a location to a HTML file from your local machine rather than a URL.

What you should use instead is:

```
.get('https://www.google.de/')
```

This will resolve that error for you!

Just for the record - the use of `.get(require.toUrl())` is no longer used in intern **version 4**. With version 4, you use `.get()` regardless of whether you're using a URL or a file.